# How to connect to SQL Server 2008 with C# application compiled in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have written a desktop based application in C#, but my customer with a Windows 7 computer can't connect the application to SQL Server 2008.

When I install SQL Server 2008 Express and run the application, I get this error:

[image]

I don't know how resolve it. The application is working absolutely fine on my computer. Please help.

Comment: Error is self explanatory. You need to check Connection String.

Comment: Is the local sql express instance is running ?

Comment: yes local sql express is running.

Comment: This is my Connection String @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="+currdir+"\\data\\library.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

*currdir is path of current directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So obviously, on your development system, you're using SQL Server **LocalDB** (a developer-specific version of SQL Server Express). So you have `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` as your server/instance name.

However, when you install the SQL Server **Express** version, this is installed (by default, unless you've changed it during install) as `YourMachine\SQLEXPRESS` (where `YourMachine` is your machine's name, and `SQLEXPRESS` is the default **instance name** for SQL Server Express).

Hence, to connect to your database - if it's installed on SQL Server Express, you need to use **this connection string** (instead of what you have now):

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="+currdir+"\\‌​data\\library.mdf;In‌​tegrated Security=SSPI;"
```

The `.` stands for "this local computer" - or you can specify the actual computer's name, if the SQL Server is installed on *another* computer.

Also, I **would strongly recommend** against using the `AttachDbFileName=` mechanism in SQL Server Express / LocalDB. As convenient as it might be in development, it has its share of troubles and issues. After all, SQL Server ***IS*** a server-based system - you should *really* install the database **on a server** and let that server handle all the details of file management.....